# Random WordPress Admin 404s

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

I've been getting completely random 404 errors when using the backend of WordPress. These errors are for completely legitimate admin pages. The workaround is to refresh the page – which usually works the second time around.

I've seen this problem reported [elsewhere](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/252861) but no solution. Wondering if anyone here has good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

1. Have you made any modifications to the htaccess file?
2. Are any of your plugins modifying htaccess?
3. Look at the servers access.log and error.log files to see if there's any odd behavior.
4. Check your version of php and version of wordpress and make sure they're not too old/too new.

The intermittent-ness is odd, though. I haven't experienced this using the latest version of Wordpress and php 5.

Comment: 1. I haven't manually made modifications.
2. The "Redirect" plugin mods .htaccess, but that shouldn't affect admin pages.
3. I will take a look at the logs.
4. Both PHP and WP are the latest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a load-balanced environment?
You may have these pages not deployed to some of the servers in the farm.